# Ways to assign blocks in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-blocks

In drupal 7, Is there other ways to assign blocks to regions without doing it in admin/structure/block or in panels? I have this client and i can't seem to find where they are actually assigning the blocks to region. They are not using panels, and the there are no assigned blocks in admin/structure/block

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to use Context module : 
https://www.drupal.org/project/context

Your description seems to be a use case of this module ;)

With it, you will see nothing assigned in admin/structure/block. just a new menu "context" in which you will find some context, wich conditions and reaction. the logic could be something like

"I am on the /toto/tutu page, so block 1 is in region R1 and block 2 is in region R2".

Comment: That was it! thank you very much. i would have voted but i lack reputations, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 additional ways that could be useful sometime:

1. Using Display Suite (https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) you can put a field that shows a block under a certain display of an entity (ex. node, user)
2. You can use a field that references a block. See https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock and https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference

Hope that helps.